# Can you play European N64 games on a Japanese console?

Tags: region-lock, nintendo-64

Can you play European N64 games on a Japanese console?  That's the question.  I can get a Japanese console pretty cheap, but I've collected quite a few EU games.

Comment: N64 has a region lock chip for its games, so even if the japanese console worked (NTSC), you'd need an adapter to play the games. Adapters are said to not work for all games. IMO, it's not worth it, just buy a PAL N64 if you're in Europe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

N64 has a region lock chip for its games, so even if the japanese console worked (NTSC), you'd need an adapter to play the games. Adapters are said to not work for all games. IMO, it's not worth it, just buy a PAL N64 if you're in Europe. – [Xander](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/197485/xander) in [a comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/348570/can-you-play-european-n64-games-on-a-japanese-console#comment490389_348570)